# Example of ring $R$ when $(R,.)$ forms a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

> If $(R,+,.)$ is a ring and $(R,.)$ is monoid then is $(R,.)$ is a
>   group or not?

This statment is false in general as,it is not necessary that multiplicative inverse of each element exists,as an example multiplicative inverse of 2 does not exist in ($\mathbb Z$,.)

I need an example of $R$ when $(R,.)$ forms a group

Comment: $0$ will be a problem.

Comment: @Randall:Means there does not exist any such group??

Comment: The "maximal" question you can ask is:  for what rings $(R, +, \times)$ is $(R-\{0\}, \times)$ a group?

Comment: Is there any ring which forms a group with second binary operation??

Comment: No:  unless $R=\{0\}$, $0$ will not be invertible under mult.

Comment: The only ring with this property is $R=\{0\}$ with $0+0=0$ and $0\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: @Randall:Then the field will answer this quesion if we considr only non-zero elements/

Comment: Fields are examples, yes.  There are others, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the first properties of rings that are derived from the axioms is
$$
r0=0
$$
for every $r\in R$.

Suppose $0$ has an inverse, $0^{-1}$. Then, for every $r\in R$,
$$
r=r1=r(0^{-1}0)=(r0^{-1})0=0
$$
so the only element of $R$ is $0$.